# Does a computer connected with a 4G USB dongle have a unique public IP address?

Tags: networking, router, ip, dongle

I will need my computer to have a unique public IP address meaning an IP address that no other device is having. I will be using it to receive UDP packet from another device that is not on the same network.

I can't tether internet from phone to computer because both phone and computer will have the same public IP and the UDP packet will be received on the phone instead of computer.

I am wondering if buying a 4G USB dongle will solve my problem. The USB dongle should not have an ip address. Dongle should only serves to give me IP address on my computer.

Comment: Depends on the wireless operator. Most only hand out private IP addresses for cellular modems. You should be asking people who are using whatever wireless operator you're interested in using.

Comment: You're more likely to get a unique IP address if you use a wireless operator that supports IPV6. Does the other device that will be sending the udp packet have IPV6 connectivity?

Comment: sorry i am new in this area. when i googled for my public ip on mobile, though same operator as another mobile, both mobile have different public ip. And the public ip is solely for the mobile. I want the same behaviour to be on my computer.

Comment: In all likelihood, the public address you see for your wireless carrier is shared among other users via NAT. Don't go by what a web site tells you, look at the address assigned to the device in the device. It is most likely private or shared addressing, but some wireless providers actually use public addressing they don't own because they use NAT. This can cause problems, too.

Comment: you need to [open a port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) so that the packet is sent to the correct device if you're behind NAT

Answer (score 1):

Since IP4 addresses are running out, I would *highly* suspect that it is not a public address.  Devices, such as phones and dongles are often off, so using a static public IP address would be a big waste.

However, the *only* way to know is to talk to someone knowledgeable at the cellular carrier.  They might offer a paid static IP service.

Comment: "Unique" and "public" do not imply "static". You can dynamically assign public unique IPv4 addresses. That said, the norm is Carrier-Grade Network Address Translation in which IP addresses (but not TCP/UDP ports) are shared.

Answer (score 0):

My experiences:

4G modems have always a internal network with internal IP address towards you router or computer. Even you have static public IP address from the mobile operator/carrier, incoming request can not route to you internal IP i.e. router and computer, since there are no way to forward it.

I have try many 4G modems with same result, all 4G modem is designed for outgoing Ip request, so you can not have e.g. web server behind the 4G modem.

The only working solution is to buy 3G modems for WCDMA, it always works, with direct connection to the router or computer.

BR
Peter

Comment: "IP request" does not really make sense, as IP is a connectionless protocol. IP has no idea whether a specific packet is a request or a reply. This is typically handled by TCP.

Comment: wrong. That all depends on the carrier. Nothing prevents a 2G or 3G carrier to not use a carrier-grade NAT

Answer (score -1):

is "sharing phone internet" your only option? if you can access to a wifi internet, in modem configuration in NAT you can set your preferred connection directed to a specific local IP address

Comment: I need to use 2/3/4G network. will not have access to wifi.

Comment: u can buy dedicated server and use it instead of your computer. sorry for cellular phones i have no other idea as DG cant be controlled by us